# How can I style jQuery-UI autocomplete differently than jQuery-UI tabs?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using two jquery ui widgets, autocomplete and tabs.

They each have their own stylesheets in `jquery.ui.autocomplete.css` and `jquery.ui.tabs.css` respectively, however they share a lot of styles in `jquery.ui.theme.css`.  When I make a change to the styles in `jquery.ui.theme.css` it affects both the autocomplete and the tabs.  How can I customize the styles different for autocomplete and tabs?

One thing I would like to change is the rounded edges on the background hover effect for the autocomplete.  The proper .css change to this is

> `.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl {
>   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px; -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; }`

However I would like the tabs to be rounded.  So the change I would make is change the radius from `0px` to `5px`.

Comment: just put style='' into the tags, that will overwrite anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put style which you want to customize, for example at head section like below:

`#my-tab .ui-corner-all, #my-tab .ui-corner-top, #my-tab .ui-corner-left, #my-tab .ui-corner-tl { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px; -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; }`

`my-tab` being your jquery-ui tab div id

edit:

from [jquery ui tabs documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#theming)

Your rendred html will look like:

```
<div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="tabs">
   <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
   <div class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab one content goes here.</p>
   </div>
    ...
</div>
```

for "menu", you will override by:

```
#ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav>li a { color: red !important }
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any tips for how to customize the autocomplete menu in the same way you suggested for tabs?  The autocomplete menu does not have an id attribute and the menu is dynamically generated, so I'm having some difficulty there.